# Where does the timezone for date and strftime come from?

Tags: c, linux, date, timezone, strftime

Im curious because I checked on a linux host in Sydney, Australia and the date command says `EST` as the timezone, as does `strftime(tz, sizeof(tz), "%Z", &time)` when running a simple C binary to print that out. However, I know the timezone is `AEST`. Are timezone abbreviations truncated? Where can I find out more about this?

Comment: What does `date +'%z %Z'` print out?

Comment: What does `echo "$TZ, $(< /etc/timezone)"` say?

Comment: Interesting. +1000 is definitely Australia, not US East Coast. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations , they are both abbreviated "EST", although "AEST" is also valid.

Comment: @thatotherguy, there is no /etc/timezone but `readlink -f /etc/localtime` says "/usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia/Sydney" and `TZ` is not set

Comment: Huh. `TZ=Australia/Sydney date` shows AEST on my Ubuntu system.

Comment: @thatotherguy oh this is not ubuntu flavor of linux

Comment: POSIX allows for more than 3 characters in a timezone name.  The timezone local file has some issues.  Use zdump on the timezone file you are using - it should diplay a lot of stuff, but you can easily see AEST versus EST.

Comment: @PalaceChan Sorry, I meant it as a data point showing that "EST" is not necessarily the Australian timezone name on all Linux systems, and gave an example of where it's not. I didn't mean to claim that you ran Ubuntu. Maybe in turn you can reveal what kind of system you run where it does show "EST"?

Comment: @jimmcnamara, how do i find the timezone local file?

Comment: @thatotherguy oh, using redhat

Comment: Red hat?  Means almost everything may be different from LInux :( .  In Linux usually : /usr/share/zoneinfo/[country], example /usr/share/zoneinfo/US.  I do not know Redhat well enough to say definitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Australian time zone abbreviations [changed in tzdb 2014f](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2014-August/000023.html), released in August 2014.

You simply need to update your time zone data file to the current version (2015b as of this writing).  On linux, this is usually in the `tzdata` package, which you can update using `apt-get`, or `rpm`, or whatever is appropriate for your distro.

Answer (score 0):

the current timezone is typically in an environment variable and/or in a special file in /etc/  in linux